# c socket port number as cmd line argument is changed?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, casting, port

I'm writing my first C program with sockets.  I want my server program to take the TCP port number as the only command line argument.  Here's a condensed version of my code (compiled on GCC, running on Linux):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int listenfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  printf("Server::  About to set %hu as the port...\n", (unsigned short)strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0));
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0));

  bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  printf("Server::  About to listen on port %hu...\n", serv_addr.sin_port);
  listen(listenfd, 10);

}
```

Output of this program is:

```
[Linux]$ ./server.exe 12345
Server::  About to set 12345 as the port...
Server::  About to listen on port 14640...
^C
[Linux]$
```

As you can see, I'm trying to tell the server that I want TCP port 12345, but it is somehow getting garbled into TCP port 14640.  Not surprisingly, when I run my client program (`./client.exe 127.0.0.1 12345`), the client gets a "Connection Refused," meaning no-one is listening on port 12345.  Ditto if I run (`./client.exe 127.0.0.1 14640`).

So I'm scratching me head on this one.  I'm assuming this is some kind of casting or data handling issue, because if replace this line:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0));
```

with this:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
```

(aka, hardcode the TCP port), the socket works fine and client & server can communicate all they want.

A little Internet research tells me that the TCP port is stored as a unsigned short in the `struct sockaddr_in` and that's why my code is bending over backwards to hammer the data into the right format.  I've tried a lot of other ways to massage the port number; trying to use `atoi(argv[1])` and then casting the returned integer as an unsigned short, for example, gives the exact same result.

Any advice?  Is this an `htons()` issue?  A formatting or casting issue?

Thanks, -RAO

Comment: 12345 -> 0x3039, 0x3930 -> 14640. This sounds like little endian vs. big endian issue...

Comment: @Scheff - Huh - thanks!  You are suggesting this is something system-specific upon on the Linux machine I am using?

Comment: I just checked how `sockaddr_in.sin_port` has to be defined. (I wondered about `htons()` but found this: [C Programming/Networking in UNIX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Networking_in_UNIX)).

Comment: `memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));` is not doing what you think it is. `'0'` is the ASCII character with integer value 48 decimal (see http://www.asciitable.com/). You want the null character, integer value zero, i.e. `0` (no quotes -- this parm is an `int`). This only matters of course if you don't initialise every field in the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 printf("Server::  About to listen on port %hu...\n", serv_addr.sin_port);
```

That doesn't work. The `%hu` format specifier is for unsigned integers in native format. The `sin_port` field is not in native format, it's in network format. So you can't print it this way.

You can convert it into native byte order with `ntohs` and then print it, if you want:

```
printf("Server::  About to listen on port %hu...\n", ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));
```

Comment: Alternatively, save the result of `strtoul()` to a local variable first, and then you can print that variable as-is, and convert the value to network byte order when assigning the variable to `serv_addr.sin_port`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(*(argv+2));
```

It worked for me. `atoi()` accepts integers and `inet_addr()` accepts strings as arguments. Make sure you pass a string to `inet_addr()` failing which also may refuse connection